# Kubernetes GKE Error dialing backend: EOF on random exec command

Tags: networking, kubernetes, eof, google-kubernetes-engine

On GKE we experiencing some random error with the API.
Many time ago we have "Error dialing backend: EOF".

We use Jenkins on top of K8s to manage our build. And afew time ago job is killed with this error:

```
Executing shell script inside container [protobuf] of pod [kubernetes-bad0aa993add416e80bdc1e66d1b30fc-536045ac8bbe]
java.net.ProtocolException: Expected HTTP 101 response but was '500 Internal Server Error'
    at com.squareup.okhttp.ws.WebSocketCall.createWebSocket(WebSocketCall.java:123)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.ws.WebSocketCall.access$000(WebSocketCall.java:40)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.ws.WebSocketCall$1.onResponse(WebSocketCall.java:98)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.Call$AsyncCall.execute(Call.java:177)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:33)
    at 


  java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at 

 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

This case looks a lot like: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/issues/3247

Many Audit log url:

```
permission:  "io.k8s.core.v1.pods.exec.create"     
resource:  "core/v1/namespaces/default/pods/pubsub-6132c0bc-2542-46a2-8041-c865f238698d-4ccc0-c1nkz-lqg5x/exec/pubsub-6132c0bc-2542-46a2-8041-c865f238698d-4ccc0-c1nkz-lqg5x"
```

and

```
permission:  "io.k8s.core.v1.pods.exec.get"     
resource:  "core/v1/namespaces/default/pods/pubsub-a5a21f14-0bd1-4338-87b1-8658c3bbc7ad-9gm4n-8nz14/exec"
```

But i don't unerstand why this error comes on Kubernetes...

**Update:**

Those error can be validated with kube-state-metrics with 2 of them:
- ssh_tunnel_open_count
- ssh_tunnel_open_fail_count

For me the number of open tunnel ssh fail grow with more than 200 ssh tunnel open.

For information, we have make some test with GKE
- swith from zonal to regional cluster
- use new native IP (old alias IP)
But this not solve the problem.

After disabling auto-scaling on node-pool , we have no more error.

Comment: If you believe it to be a GKE issue, I would suggest you to open a private issue report using [this link](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187164) providing related information(eg: project-id, cluster-name, pods, K8 version etc.) and replication steps (if possible) to verify.

Comment: I've been investigating this behavior and the [corresponding issue in Jenkins](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-59652?page=com.atlassian.streams.streams-jira-plugin%3Aactivity-stream-issue-tab) as well as `gitlab-runner`. It seem like GitLab solved the problem by catching `java.net.ProtocolException` and retrying. Jenkins sees the issues within K8s. In a first test retrying seems to be a workaround, however this requires every statement in Jenkinsfiles to be wrapped in a retry function (groovy closures are helping, but it's still an insane impact). Any updates or even a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I could fix this issue by deactivating auto-scaling profile `optimize-utilization`/resetting the profile back to the default `balanced`. `optimize-utilization` is in beta status anyway.